# Flex in IE11: width100% not working with nested flex and direction 'column'

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I need an image in nested flex containers to have width 100%, but this doesn´t work in IE11 when the container has `flex-direction: column`. I tried:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: calc( 100% - 0.1px );
}
```

but this also doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
section, .articles-wrapper, .article-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.article-wrapper {
  flex-direction: column;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

html:

```
<section>
  <div class="articles-wrapper">
    <div class="article-wrapper">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x150">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Try adding `min-width: 0` to your elements... You've defined three flex containers. You've applied `flex-direction: column` to one of them. This means the other two are `flex-direction: row` by default. Now you have to deal with the *default minimum width of flex items*, which doesn't allow items to be shorter than their content.

Comment: Given the fact that IE is quite buggy when it comes to Flexbox, there might be different solutions to your problem, based on what you actually is trying to achieve. If you increase your sample code so it make more sence, we will be able to suggest a proper answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for the replies. I've eliminated `flex` from the code and solved the thing with floating elements. I prefer to use flex, but it's a tough deal with IE 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you inspected the page to see how the elements are laid out?

The image actually ***is*** taking up 100% of it's parent's width, because by default flex-items are not allowed to grow to fill the flex container but expand only enough to display their content.

Both the `.articles-wrapper` and `.article-wrapper` elements need to be explicitly allowed to grow, either by specifying `flex-grow: 1;` or using the shorthand property `flex` with one of several values:

```
.articles-wrapper, .article-wrapper {
    flex: auto; /* shorthand for flex: 1 1 auto; */
}
```

OR

```
.articles-wrapper, .article-wrapper {
    flex: 1; /* shorthand for flex: 1 1 0%; */
}
```

As you get deeper into using flexbox, I recommend keeping Philip Walton's [Flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) repo at hand which lists common bugs for all browsers as well as workarounds for each.

EDIT Michiel: `flex: 1` works in IE11, except that the aspect ratio is not maintained when the window is scaled to a smaller size than the image size. This 'feature' is documented in [Flexbugs #5](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-5), and can be solved by adding a non-flex wrapper:

```
<section>
  <div class="articles-wrapper">
    <div class="article-wrapper">
      <div> <!-- ADDED NON-FLEX WRAPPER -->
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x150">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Michiel Good catch on that edit! I was focusing on scaling up and forgot to check when scaling down. I'm (im)patiently waiting for the day we no longer have to worry about supporting IE11.